# React hooks: setState() with string that contains html?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to setState from a json file value that contains html. So something like:

```
...
const quote = [quote, setQuote] = useState('');

const quotes = [
    { quote: "Some text." },
    { quote: 'Some text with <span class="red">HTML</span>.' },
  ];
  const handleClick = () => {
    setQuote(quotes[1].quote);
  };
...
return (
  <div>{quote}</div> // right now it's printing the html as text.
);
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @hgb123 "Some text with HTML" where the html itself, i.e. `<span class="red">...` is not printed.

Comment: that is not how it works.  if you want react components then you will need logic... like a switch maybe? and depending on the chosen index to output a particular component(div???)

Comment: trying to do what you are doing defeats the purpose of REACT.... it is more like jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Use [dangeriouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to parse and render an HTML string. You may also want to cleanse/sanitize any values with [DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify).

Example:

```
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";

...

const quote = [quote, setQuote] = useState('');

const quotes = [
  { quote: "Some text." },
  { quote: 'Some text with <span class="red">HTML</span>.' },
];
const handleClick = () => {
  setQuote(quotes[1].quote);
};

...

return (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML ={{ __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(quote) }} />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert raw HTML using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
return (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: quote }}></div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Injecting html from text is always a risk, but I think this should work:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

...
const quoteRef = useRef(null);

const quotes = [
    { quote: "Some text." },
    { quote: 'Some text with <span class="red">HTML</span>.' },
  ];
  const handleClick = () => {
    if(!quoteRef.current) return; //Just in case the element got deleted
    quoteRef.current.innerHTML = quotes[1].quote;
  };
...
return (
  <div ref={quoteRef}>{quote}</div> // right now it's printing the html as text.
);
```